# Problema ao gerar valor aleatório usando a classe Random

Tags: java, random

O programa está gerando um valor aleatório, mas às vezes ele estoura a array, ou simplesmente não exibe nada.

Exemplos do erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Sorteio {

    public static void main(String []args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Informe o numero de pessoas no sorteio: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        String pessoa [] = new String [n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("Informe a " + (i + 1) + "a pessoa: ");
            pessoa[i] = sc.nextLine();
            if (i == 0) sc.nextLine();
        }

        Random rd = new Random();

        System.out.println("O vencedor do sorteio e: " + pessoa[rd.nextInt(n)]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é esse seu `if (i == 0) sc.nextLine();` que está no lugar errado.

Observe que isso está depois da linha anterior que tem o `pessoa[i] = sc.nextLine();`. Assim, ele não atribuir uma string vazia ao nome de `pessoa[0]` e vai pular o nome que deveria ser da primeira pessoa. Assim, quando ele não mostra nada é porque a primeira pessoa havia sido sorteado.

A solução é retirar o `if` e mover esse `sc.nextLine();` para logo após o `sc.nextInt();`:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

class Sorteio {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Informe o numero de pessoas no sorteio: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        String[] pessoas = new String[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("Informe a " + (i + 1) + "a pessoa: ");
            pessoas[i] = sc.nextLine();
        }
        Random rd = new Random();
        for (int j = 0; j < 200; j++) {
            System.out.println("O vencedor do sorteio e: " + pessoas[rd.nextInt(n)]);
        }
    }
}
```

Observe que coloquei o sorteio sendo efetuado 200 vezes para te mostrar que sempre dá uma resposta que seja um dos nomes e nunca dá uma exceção.

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/4xTv4Y)

---

A necessidade de utilizar esse `nextLine()` para esvaziar o *buffer* é meio ruim. A solução é eliminar o `nextInt()` e só usar o `nextLine()`:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

class Sorteio {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Informe o numero de pessoas no sorteio: ");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        String[] pessoas = new String[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("Informe a " + (i + 1) + "a pessoa: ");
            pessoas[i] = sc.nextLine();
        }
        Random rd = new Random();
        for (int j = 0; j < 200; j++) {
            System.out.println("O vencedor do sorteio e: " + pessoas[rd.nextInt(n)]);
        }
    }
}
```

[**Veja aqui funcionndo o ideone.**](https://ideone.com/aHHgDZ)

Esse comportamento estranho ocorre com o `sc.nextInt()` e com o `sc.nextLine()` por causa desses motivos:

- O `System.in` é o objeto que fornece a outros objetos aquilo que o usuário digitou.
- O `System.in` armazena o que o usuário digitou em uma área de memória denominada de *buffer*.
- Outros objetos (no caso o `Scanner`) podem solicitar ao `System.in` para fornecer alguns dos caracteres ou bytes digitados pelo usuário. (Ele trabalha com bytes, mas esses são interpretados/convertidos em caracteres pelo `Scanner`).
- Quando existe alguma coisa no *buffer* e o `System.in` é solicitado a fornecer alguns bytes, ele irá fornecê-los ao retirá-los do início do *buffer*. Se sobrarem bytes excedentes no *buffer*, eles continuarão lá.
- Quando o *buffer* estiver vazio e o `System.in` for solicitado a fornecer alguns bytes, ele vai travar e esperar o usuário digitar algum texto **terminado com <kbd>enter</kbd>**. Esse texto, **inclusive o <kbd>enter</kbd>** é armazenado no *buffer* e então segue-se o que está no item anterior: alguns bytes são retirados do início do *buffer* e entregues. Quaisquer bytes excedentes permanecem lá.
- Quando o método `nextLine()` do `Scanner` for chamado, ele vai consumir todos os bytes que encontrar até encontrar o <kbd>enter</kbd> e devolver isso que ele consumiu **sem o <kbd>enter</kbd>**. Ou seja, ele vai consumir a primeira linha do que estiver no `System.in` e descartar o <kbd>enter</kbd>.
- Já o método `nextInt()` funciona de uma forma diferente, ele vai consumir apenas os bytes que correspondam a dígitos, deixando o <kbd>enter</kbd> para trás dentro do *buffer*.
- Desta forma, temos uma diferença importante: O `nextLine()` consome e descarta o <kbd>enter</kbd> no final da linha, mas o `nextInt()` o deixa lá. É por isso que o `nextLine()` após o `nextInt()` é necessário e ele devolve uma string vazia. A função dele é retirar o <kbd>enter</kbd> que foi largado no começo do *buffer* pelo `nextInt()`.
- Esse comportamento incoerente é resolvido ao usar-se apenas o `nextLine()` e abandonar o `nextInt()`. O `Integer.parseInt(String)` é usado para transformar a linha lida em um número.

Comment: Cara, eu usei esse `sc.nextLine` sem saber direito pra que serve. Eu tava tentando sem ele, só que ele pulava a execução de leitura da primeira pessoa, indo direto pra segunda. Eu pesquisei e vi que ele serve pra "esvaziar o buffer do teclado" (whatever it means), e depois que eu coloquei ele logo apos o `pessoas[i] = sc.nextLine()` dentro do laço `for`, percebi que ele não pulava, mas agora era necessário pressionar o enter mais uma vez após informar o nome para leitura.

Comment: A maneira que encontrei de não pular a leitura e não precisar ficar apertando enter duas vezes a cada vez que lê um valor, foi colocando esse `sc.nextLine()` somente na primeira leitura do laço. Você poderia por gentileza explicar, ou indicar algum site com explicação de para que serve esse `sc.nextLine()` avulso?

Comment: @Jow Resposta editada para explicar isso.

Comment: Entendi muito bem. Valeu por tomar seu tempo pra resolver meu problema. Ainda se deu ao trabalho de editar a resposta e acrescentar mais informação, explicando de uma maneira muito clara. Abraço!

Comment: Só uma coisa: no fim do 3º tópico de baixo para cima, não seria somente "deixando enter" ao invés "deixando o enter para trás"? @Victor Stafusa

Comment: @Jow Editei o final desse item também. Ficou mais claro?