# Exercício com HashMap

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

Estou tentando fazer esse exercício, não sei onde estou errando. Podem me ajudar?

Preciso criar um mapa que tenha por chave o número de caracteres do nome de uma cidade e por valor em uma lista com todos os nomes com esse número de caracteres.

Necessário fazer um print que indique os nomes das cidades e o número de caracteres que os nomes têm. Tente que o código tenha o mínimo de linhas possível.

Como eu fiz. Se tiverem sugestão de melhorias...

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class testeJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<Integer,String> hm=new HashMap<Integer,String>();

        Scanner nomeCidade = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner qtdCidade = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Quantidade de Cidade a Adicionar?");
        int qtd = qtdCidade.nextInt();


        for (int i = 0; i < qtd; i++) {
            System.out.println("Informe Nome da Cidade?");
            String nome = nomeCidade.nextLine();
            hm.put(i,nome);

            for (int j = 0; j < nome.length(); j++) {
                if(hm.containsKey(nome.charAt(j))){
                //ESTA DANDO ERRO NESSA LINHA ABAIXO SOLICITANDO CAST.
                    hm.put(nome.charAt(j),hm.get(nome.charAt(j))+1); 
                } else {
                    hm.put(nome.charAt(j), 1);
                }
            }

        }

        for(Map.Entry m:hm.entrySet()){  
               System.out.println(m.getKey()+" "+m.getValue());  
        } 

        nomeCidade.close();
        qtdCidade.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro, você só deve usar um `Scanner`. Nunca use ou crie mais do que um e apenas um `new Scanner(System.in)`. E não tem sentido fechá-lo.

Segundo, que nomes de classes devem ter letras maiúsculas. Ou seja, use `TesteJava` ao invés de `testeJava`.

Terceiro, que como você mesmo disse, o os valores do `Map` deveriam ser uma lista dos nomes da cidade.

Quarto, que misturar o `nextInt()` com o `nextLine()` no `Scanner` traz resultados inesperados e confusos. [**Veja nessa minha outra resposta uma explicação disso.**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/237085/132)

Quinto, use a sintaxe do diamante se possível.

Sexto, prefira declarar variáveis cujos tipos sejam abstrações, e não implementações. Ou seja, evite variáveis cujo tipo é `HashMap` ao invés de `Map`.

Sétimo, isso que você quer fazer fica bem mais fácil se você usar o método [`compute(K, BiFunction<? super K, ? super V, ? extends V>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-).

Oitavo, evite ao máximo usar tipos que são genéricos sem os genéricos.

Eis o seu código corrigido:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

class TesteJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Quantidade de cidades a adicionar?");
        int qtd = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < qtd; i++) {
            System.out.println("Nome da " + (i + 1) + "a cidade?");
            String nome = scan.nextLine();
            map.compute(nome.length(), (k, v) -> {
                List<String> nomes = v != null ? v : new ArrayList<>();
                nomes.add(nome);
                return nomes;
            });
        }

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {  
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());  
        } 
    }
}
```

Se para esse código for dada essa entrada:

```
21
Bauru
Poá
Londrina
Franca
Itapevi
Osasco
Salvador
Suzano
São Paulo
Vitória
Cuiabá
Maceió
Belém
Curitiba
Macapá
Rio Branco
Manaus
Belo Horizonte
Recife
Itu
Rio de Janeiro
```

Essa será a saída produzida no final:

```
3 [Poá, Itu]
5 [Bauru, Belém]
6 [Franca, Osasco, Suzano, Cuiabá, Maceió, Macapá, Manaus, Recife]
7 [Itapevi, Vitória]
8 [Londrina, Salvador, Curitiba]
9 [São Paulo]
10 [Rio Branco]
14 [Belo Horizonte, Rio de Janeiro]
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/6ml7md)

Comment: Obrigado Victor pelas dicas. 

Quando você diz,  sintaxe do diamante se possível: você quer dizer: `Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();` 

O `map.compute` é meio confuso para mim, irei estudar mais sobre o mesmo, parece que ele uma uma sintaxe lambda, isso ?

Comment: @Slinkey99 Sim, estou usando sintaxe lambda aqui. O diamante é esse `<>` mesmo.

Answer (score -3):

fala mano voltei do futuro pra falar de uma solução simples que fiz caso for uma lista pronta:

```
List<String> pais = new LinkedList<>(){{
        add("brasil");
        add("korea");
    }};

    Map<Integer,String> mapas = new HashMap<>();
    for (String p: pais) {
        mapas.put(p.length(),p);
    }
    System.out.println(mapas);
    for (Map.Entry<Integer,String> entry: mapas.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("numeros de caractere: "+
                entry.getKey()+" pais:"+ entry.getValue());
    }
```

saída

```
numeros de caractere: 5 pais:korea
numeros de caractere: 6 pais:brasil
```